# Install MacVim in Sierra

Tags: homebrew, macos-sierra, macvim

I have a new laptop with Sierra. I brought my applications from my old mac with Time Machine and most of them are working fine. However, Macvim disappeared. I tried to install it. 
I tried to re-install it by installing Homebrew and brew installing macvim. The install looks successful, but I still cannot find nor use macvim. I guess this is a matter again of application files no longer being in /usr/ but in Library/, but honestly I am a bit lost as to how to figure out whether this is the problem and how to fix it.

Can you please help me out with this?

How I installed Homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

How I installed Macvim:

```
brew install macvim
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MacVim is keg-only.

If you run this command after installation:

```
brew linkapps
```

you will find MacVim in your Applications folder in finder.

Comment: Thank you. When I run the `$(brew --prefix)`... command it returns:  `/usr/local/bin/macvim: No such file or directory`

Comment: I just saw that macvim is keg-only, which means it is not linked to ```/usr/local/```. You will find the macOS Application bundle in ```/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-130/```, with an executable in ```/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-130/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/MacVim```

Comment: And how can I use it, then?

Comment: See updated answer, brew provides a tool to link keg-only applications to your applications folder.

Comment: I get this warning: "Warning: `brew linkapps` has been deprecated and will eventually be removed! Unfortunately `brew linkapps` cannot behave nicely with e.g. Spotlight using either aliases or symlinks and Homebrew formulae do not build "proper" `.app` bundles that can be relocated. Instead, please consider using `brew cask` and migrate formulae using `.app`s to casks."

Answer (score 2):

Since `linkapps` is now deprecated, I've had to manually link `.app` via

```
ln -Fs `find /usr/local -name "MacVim.app"` /Applications/MacVim.app
```

Unfortunately, *Spotlight* cannot find *MacVim* this way. Therefore, I've (after opening the app by double-clicking on the icon in *Finder*'s *Applications* folder) right-clicked on the app's icon on the dock and selected *Option -> Keep in Dock*.

Answer (score 2):

The symbolic soft link solution described by @laylaylom works; but I am having trouble setting MacVim as my default app for some filetype. Then I found this from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/why-cant-i-use-app-bundles-symlinked-into-applications-as-default-in-the-ope/63606#63606):

```
% mkdir ~/Applications/Emacs.app
% ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/23.2/Emacs.app/Contents ~/Applications/Emacs.app
```

That solution was for Emacs.app but it can work with MacVim as well:

```
% mkdir ~/Applications/MacVim.app
% ln -Fs /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.1-151/MacVim.app/Contents ~/Applications/MacVim.app
```

Comment: Thanks for the great solution!

Answer (score 2):

There is now a cask for MacVim, but it's not the default. The correct command is:

```
brew install homebrew/cask/macvim
```

This will install MacVim in the Applications folder, and make it available to Spotlight.

Comment: now is `brew install --cask macvim`, https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/macvim